# NullReferenceException thrown while reading config.json in MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm  working on MVC6 webapp. My Startup.cs has the following code-

```
public class Startup
{
    public static Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       //following line throws NullReferenceException
       Configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile("config.json").AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
}
```

config.json-

```
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;"
         }
     }
}
```

Any help?

> UPDATE: This question is not all about NullReferenceException. In
>   ASP.NET-5 MVC-6, config.json is a new addition. I am using the code as
>   it is found in several blogs. Here are few links-
>
> - http://bitoftech.net/2014/11/18/getting-started-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-entity-framework-7/
> - https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs
> - http://forums.asp.net/t/1999143.aspx?How+to+configure+connection+string+in+MVC+6+in+ASP+NET+vNext
> - http://blog.developers.ba/read-config-file-in-asp-net-vnext/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RowlandShaw this not duplicating the question you mentioned. This problem is elsewhere. So, it should not be closed.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - The problem is different here. This question should get an answer.

Comment: What version are you using, beta4?

Comment: You could at least figure out if `new Configuration()`, `AddJsonFile()` or `AddEnvironmentVariables()` throws the NRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the RTM version of Visual Studio you must be working with beta5 revision of asp.net. In this version namespaces for configuration has been changed.

**EDIT:** You must add this package: `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json`

This code must work for you:

```
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime;

namespace Test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```