# Where is AddJsonFile extenstion method for Autofac 4.0

Tags: autofac, autofac-configuration

In the Autofac [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html), they provide a brief example of injecting a component via a service...

However, I'm unable to locate the extension method AddJsonFile ..

The provided snippet is:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.AddJsonFile("autofac.json");
```

Bonus: How to find a extension method when the "Using" statements are not provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382481/why-visual-studio-tell-me-that-addjsonfile-method-is-not-define-in-configurati) in a comment after scrolling down.  They are located Nuget Package:
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.XML -or- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json