# Azure Functions deployment fails because pip install cannot find environment variable / app setting

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

**EDIT:** My flaw when deploying to Azure was that I was not saving the new Application settings I was introducing *facepalm*. Saving `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=https://<token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<gituser>` allows `pip` to finally install my private library.

However, it still doesn't work when locally debugging with F5 on VSCode, regardless of my `local.settings.json`. Below I'll describe the hack that makes it work locally, but I would prefer to resolve why it doesn't work from my local settings.

My requirements.txt indicates the private library as `<package_name> @ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<gituser>/<repo>/<branch>/dist/<package_name>0.1.11-py3-none-any.whl`. Based on the fact that adding an `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` in Azure allows the deployment, I am trying to imitate that in my `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    ...
    "PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL": "https://<token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<gituser>",
    ...
  }
}
```

However, I get a 404 error when the Azure's `pip` tries to install from `requirements.txt`.

Locally, in `tasks.json`, if I set that env var before I run pip install, the F5 starts working:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
        },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
            ...
            "windows": {
                "command": "$env:PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL = 'https://<token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<gituser>'; ${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

In other words, my F5 is not reading the env var from `local.settings.json` before the `pip install` task runs (note that the function itself is properly receiving the env vars as evidenced by successful os.environ[] calls). Also note that locally it does work if I set the env var in `tasks.json`, which is not ideal. I prefer my `local.settings.json` to mirror my Application settings on Azure.

Comment: Are you loading local.settings.json when azure function app starts? You need to load it manually. By default az func is not loading it. Here is an example mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382481/why-does-visual-studio-tell-me-that-the-addjsonfile-method-is-not-defined

Comment: Thanks @MarekB for the reply. No I am not loading local.settings.json manually. Didn't think I needed to since os.environ[] reads it fine in __init__.py. Sorry, I'm not able to draw a parallel between your linked example (C#) and mine (Python). For example, there's a mention of project.json, which my project lacks. In my .vscode folder I have 4 json files, not sure if it's one of those. Could you please describe how I can load local.settings.json?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I totally ignored the fact that you're using pyhon :D Forgive me, please ignore my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3054) it has been confirmed that this is expected behavior and that my workaround is valid:

> "local.settings.json" is unique to core tools and thus only applies
> during the func start command. Since "pip install" happen before
> func start, you would have to set the env var elsewhere (and yes
> tasks.json is a good place).